# Unique Number Creation and Database Registration

Tags: android

I want the application to create a unique 4-digit code and save it to the firebase database. This code will not change when the app is exited and entered again.How do I do that?
[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9860n.jpg)

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @CyanDeveloper-AngeloCimino nope

Answer (score 0):

Starting talk about the combinations.. this type of code (4-digits) can give life to **only 10.000 users**. If your app has 10.001 user, probably it will **crash** or will be **unusefull**.

Avoiding talk about the combinations, instead, firebase can't do this with its API or premade functions. You need to implement this with you code, in the android app or (recommended) in some "Functions". If you don't need that this code is random, you can have a field on your database that do as a **counter**.

Every time an user need that his code to be created (for example on registration), you simply retrieve the counter value on the db and increment, assigning it to the user code field. In this way, the first user of your app will be the code 0000. The next, will have 0001,0002,etc.. The last user that can be registered will have the code 9999.

As said above, retrieving the user data from database after the registration, you'll have the previous saved user code too, so it **will not change**.

If you need more help, please tell us more about your app or scope.

Comment: Once the user has access to the code, it will not need the application. And I'il erase the code from the database. For example, you have downloaded my app and it is your code: 4321. I saw the code in the database and you used it, and then I deleted it from the database. So, after the user receives the code does not need to implement. And I'm deleting the code from the database.

Comment: @ArthurFrankAsabiyovic I can't understand this kind of technique but if you need it you have 2 chances:

1)You must orient to a SQL database, instead of a NO-SQL as Firebase is

2)Fill you db with a list of children with fields "code:NNNN" and "user:null"

If you use the 2th option, you need to check on your db if there is at least one child with user field null. If yes, put the username or his account key there and show the code to the user. Once the code become unusefull, simply set the "user" field to null and the code will be available again for another user.

Comment: @ArthurFrankAsabiyovic This type of technique is boring at first unless you create a script to automatically fill in the db before the app is released. Obviously, I suggest you use the script instead of filling the database "by hand".